# Pass an array without displaying it in url

Tags: php, arrays, forms, symfony

### What I am trying to do :

I am currently installing authentication through LinkedIn OAuth on my symfony2 app.

In my userController, I have a function for fetching linkedin data, and another one for creating a new user.

This create a new user function can handle both linkedin user (whith the help of an array passed as a parameter) and non-linkedin users (through a form in a POST request) :

```
public function createUserAction($from_linkedin = false, $linkedin_data = null)
{
    $user = new User();
    if(!from_linkedin) {
        // User comes from the registration form
        $user = $post_data,
    } else {
        // User comes from linkedin OAuth
        $user = $linkedin_data;
    }
    $em->persist($user);
    $em->flush();
 }
```

I would like to let my linkedin OAuth users chose a password, so they can connect with linkedin or a standard email/password form in the future. I also feel this is more secure.

In order to do that, i created an intermediary function to display a password form to users. This form is displayed after the linkedin call and before the registration function

```
protected function chosePasswordAction($linkedin_data)
{
    $form = createForm(new ChosePasswordType);
    if($method = POST) {
        $linkedin_data["password"] = $post_data["password"];

        return createUserAction(true, $linkedin_data);
    }

    return $this->renderView("chosePassword.html.twig", array(
        'form' => $form,
        'data' => $linkedin_data,
    ));
}
```

### What is my problem :

The form is displayed well, but I have an error when I come back from it in the POST request. The $linkedin_data array is missing, so the chosePassword() function returns an error :

```
Controller "Bundle\Controller\UserController::chosePasswordAction()" 
requires that you provide a value for the "$linkedin_data" argument 
(because there is no default value or because there is a non optional 
argument after this one).
```

The only method i know it to add the $linkedin_data array as a parameter in the form route, but it doesn't feel secure at all. How can I pass it easilly without risk?

Comment: Are two requests happening? Are you passing the linkedin data back to the password form? You can either store the data on server-side until they set a password, then attach the password/authentication data, or you have to send it back to the user's set-password form via hidden inputs, and process the linkedin data when they re-submit it to your server.

Comment: Are you saying that everything works fine when you do a GET request rather than a POST?

Comment: @Fydo: passing the linkedin data to the password form is what I'd like to achieve. Send it via hidden inputs looks like the best option in this case, even if it feels a little hackish for such a sensitive part of the app. Your answer confirms my first intuition though, i'll give it a go - thanks ;).

Comment: @MrLister Nope I'm dealing with POST only here, I'd rather not use any GET method for password, user private data etc. in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that I know what you're doing, I would consider storing the data in php's [$_SESSION](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) when you first receive it. Don't bother sending it back and forth again. It's not only hackish, but is prone to tampering, especially if your not running https where Linedin most likely is.

Happy Coding!

Comment: I was about to comment on your first answer again, to favor this option instead of hidden inputs in the form. Thanks.